# Generating set of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Claim:** 
The smallest subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$  containing the matrices of the form
$\begin{pmatrix} 1&b\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&\frac1a \end{pmatrix}$ and
$\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$ is $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

---

Let $F:=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{R}):c\ne0\right\}$

And for any $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with $c\ne0$ we have
$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1&\frac{a}{c}\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} c&0\\0&\frac1c \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1&\frac{d}{c}\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$

Then the subgroup generated by the matrices of the form
$\begin{pmatrix} 1&b\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0&\frac1a \end{pmatrix}$ and
$\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix}$
definitely contains $F$.

Now it can be shown that $F$ is dense in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

But how do we use this fact to reach the above claim?

Comment: Can you show directly that the subset with $c=0$ is also in the subgroup you've generated?

Comment: Try to do it without using the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$